# Filtering Excel Table with date in multipe columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has two date columns.  For simplicity, lets say and "in date" and "out date."  I would like to filter the table to see activity of a date in either column.

With the standard autofilter, it will execute filter where "in date" and "out date" are both the date it will show.  I don't know of a way to do if "in date" or "out date" = user date.  I want to filter the table row when either date is the same as the selected date.  Thus, showing all rows that contain the date specified.

Can anyone help on a way to do this?  I am trying to do this VBA code so that the sheet can be very simple for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think advanced filter is the functionality you need. How are you "selecting" the date to be used for the filter?

If you want an OR filter, in the criteria put the target date on separate lines (on the same line is an AND).
     A         B
1  InDate    OutDate
2  7/17/17
3            7/17/17

If you reference your selected value in both date cells they will both update when you select your date.

Another helpful tip when doing advanced filter is define a named range for your data set, it makes executing the filter easier. Defining names for your criteria area and output area are also helpful.

When you get the filter working, record a macro (using your defined names), then add a button to the worksheet that launches the macro.

I've done similar things with the input being a datepicker object.

Good luck!